# Prevent dropdown list in collapsed bootstrap4 navbar from expanding the navbar

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, navbar, responsive

I needed a selector that doesn't collapse alongside the rest of the menu in a bootstrap v4 navbar. Got something working, too. See below.

It's a bit hacky as there are actually two language selectors, but one is hidden when the browser window is smaller than the lg-breakpoint in bootstrap. Opposite way round if it is larger than the lg-breakpoint obviously. It works fine - but there might be a more elegant way to do this.

What I don't like is that, when the nav collapses, clicking on the language selector expands the navbar by the height of the dropdown list. Obviously it has to as the language selector is wrapped in the collabsed "nav" - but I'd much rather it'd behave as it does with the lg and wider selector - there the dropdown extends beyond the navbar without changing the size of the navbar.

Is there any way around this?

See these images:

[image: Language selector in expanded menu]

[image: Language selector in collapsed menu]

[image: Language selector dropdown list expands collapsed menu]

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<!--navigation-->
<nav class="navbar sticky-top navbar-dark navbar-expand-lg">
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Page Title</a>
  <!--language selector for collapsed menu [hidden when viewport larger than medium]-->
  <div class="d-lg-none ml-auto">
    <ul class="navbar-nav">
      <li class="nav-item dropdown">
        <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">&#127760; Language</a>
        <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Language 1</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Language 2</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Language 3</a>
        </div>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-controls="navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbar">
    <div class="navbar-nav">
      <!-- page user is looking at = "nav-link active"-->
      <a class="nav-item nav-link active" href="#">Home<span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
      <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="#">Link 1</a>
      <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="#">Link 2</a>
      <div class="nav-item dropdown">
        <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">The Team</a>
        <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Link</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another Link</a>
          <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">An entirely different link</a>
        </div>
      </div>
      <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="sponsor_us.php">Link 3</a>
      <a class="nav-item nav-link disabled" href="#">inactive Link</a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!--language selector for expanded menu [hidden viewport size medium and down]-->
  <div class="d-none d-sm-none d-md-none d-lg-block d-xl-block ml-auto">
    <ul class="navbar-nav">
      <li class="nav-item dropdown">
        <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">&#127760; Language</a>
        <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Language 1</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Language 2</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Language 3</a>
        </div>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Edit: Here's a [jsfiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/Mnemon/skg8x0u6/5/) - albeit for some reason that one doesn't use the bootstrap.css file I'd added in the resources. So the menu is white, not black :). You have to change the width of the window that displays the html to see the menu expanding and collapsing.

Comment: You should use `Popover` instead of `Dropdown` i think. Here you have some more information : https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/components/popovers/

Comment: Thank you. Will experiment a bit with that. As it's a language selector it obviously needs to function as a dropdown would - am not quite sure how complicated that is with popovers.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is old, but this was the ONLY place I'd found this question asked.

Simple way:

css: `.popout { position: absolute !important;}`

now add popout class to you div that you no longer want to remain inside the navbar while the navbar is collapsed!

```html
<style>
    .popout { position: absolute !important;}
</style>
<html>
    ...
    <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right popout" ...>
        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Language 1</a>
        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Language 2</a>
        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Language 3</a>   
    </div>
</html>
```